# friendly-id custom url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have successfully integrated friendly-id and is working fine. My product can be viewed from (`localhost:3000/product/test-product`) url. What I want is to have a short url like (`localhost:3000/test-product`) for my product.

How can I achieve this in friendly-id or in rails.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom route to achieve this :

In routes.rb

```
get ':id' => 'products#show', as: :product
```

Call like

```
product_path(product.slug)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I changed it to be page (instead of products) and despite that, the URLs are all still /pages/slug-value. I'm trying this in Rails 4.2 with friendly_id 5.1. Getting frustrated because it seems like it should be simple but I'm spending a ton of time on it when I could be doing something else that actually matters :-/